# std::is_base_of and virtual base class

Tags: c++, c++11, enable-if

Is there a way to identify whether or not a base class is a virtual base class?

std::is_base_of will identify a base class, but I'm looking for something like std::is_virtual_base_of to identify a virtual base class.

This is for SFINAE purposes where I want to use dynamic_cast (less performant) when std::is_virtual_base_of is true, and static_cast (more performant) when it is false.

Comment: Found the same question here, where one of the responses summarizes how boost does it...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893791/c-can-virtual-inheritance-be-detected-at-compile-time

Comment: Not quite the same, but how about just SFINAEing on the validity of the static_cast expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class, class, class...>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type {};
  template<class...>struct voider{using type=void;};
  template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;
  template<template<class...>class Z, class... Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class... Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;
```

this lets us do modular SFINAE on a template application easily.

```
template<class Dest, class Src>
using static_cast_r = decltype(static_cast<Dest>( std::declval<Src>() ));
template<class Dest, class Src>
using can_static_cast = can_apply< static_cast_r, Dest, Src >;
```

now we can determine if we can static cast.

Now we implement it:

```
namespace details {
  template<class Dest, class Src>
  Dest derived_cast_impl( std::true_type /* can static cast */ , Src&& src )
  {
    return static_cast<Dest>(std::forward<Src>(src));
  }

  template<class Dest, class Src>
  Dest derived_cast_impl( std::false_type /* can static cast */ , Src&& src )
  {
    return dynamic_cast<Dest>(std::forward<Src>(src));
  }
}
template<class Dest, class Src>
Dest derived_cast( Src&& src ) {
  return details::derived_cast_impl<Dest>( can_static_cast<Dest, Src&&>{}, std::forward<Src>(src) );
}
```

Test code:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };

struct A : virtual Base {};
struct B : Base {};

struct Base2 {};
struct B2 : Base2 {};

int main() {
  auto* pa = derived_cast<A*>( (Base*)0 ); // static cast won't work
  (void)pa;
  auto* pb = derived_cast<B*>( (Base*)0 ); // either would work
  (void)pb;
  auto* pb2 = derived_cast<B2*>( (Base2*)0 ); // dynamic cast won't work
  (void)pb2;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c43c0a2b519cc509)

Answer (score 1):

With c++17 it's quite easy to implement.

```
#include <type_traits>

// First, a type trait to check whether a type can be static_casted to another    
template <typename From, typename To, typename = void>
struct can_static_cast: std::false_type{};

template <typename From, typename To>
struct can_static_cast<From, To, std::void_t<decltype(static_cast<To>(std::declval<From>()))>>: std::true_type{};

// Then, we apply the fact that a virtual base is first and foremost a base,
// that, however, cannot be static_casted to its derived class.
template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct is_virtual_base_of: std::conjunction<
    std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>, 
    std::negation<can_static_cast<Base*, Derived*>>
>{};

// Proof that it works.
struct Base{};
struct NonVirtual: Base{};
struct Virtual: virtual Base{};

static_assert(is_virtual_base_of<Base, NonVirtual>::value == false);
static_assert(is_virtual_base_of<Base, Virtual>::value == true);
```

See it on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/jxjq5W

With c++11 it's a tad less clean. Here it is:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename From, typename To, typename = void>
struct can_static_cast: std::false_type{};

template <typename From, typename To>
struct can_static_cast<From, To, decltype(static_cast<To>(std::declval<From>()), void())>: std::true_type{};

template <typename Base, typename Derived, typename = void>
struct is_virtual_base_of: std::false_type{};

template <typename Base, typename Derived>
struct is_virtual_base_of<Base, Derived, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value && 
    !can_static_cast<Base*, Derived*>::value
>::type>: std::true_type{};

struct Base{};
struct NonVirtual: Base{};
struct Virtual: virtual Base{};

static_assert(is_virtual_base_of<Base, NonVirtual>::value == false);
static_assert(is_virtual_base_of<Base, Virtual>::value == true);
```

See it on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/qnT6aq

Comment: Is there really a need for the `is_virtual_base_of` struct? couldn't you just have 
    
`template<class Dest, class Src>
inline constexpr bool can_static_cast_v = can_static_cast<Dest, Src>::value;` then
    `template <typename Base, typename Derived>
inline constexpr bool is_virtual_base_of_v = std::is_base_of_v <Base, Derived> && (!can_static_cast_v<Base*, Derived*>);`

Comment: @Spencer the struct can be used with metafunctions that take types rather than values. But if you don't need that, sure, you can just go ahead with the value alone.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see a C++20 solution, so have this extremely elegant concept:

```
/// Check if a type is virtually derived from all the provided BASE(s)  
template<class T, class...BASE>
concept VirtuallyDerivedFrom = ((::std::is_base_of_v<BASE, T>
        and not requires (BASE* from) { static_cast<T*>(from); }
    ) and ...);
```

[Here's the proof](https://godbolt.org/z/hKPK6a84r)

Comment: Just a comment, but in that case I'ld still keep a trait class (that way it can be easily used as a type parameter to act as a metafunction) and use that trait class for the concept